# Compact way to store floating points

Tags: arrays, floating-point, byte, storage

I'm serializing a byte array of info, 6 individual bytes, and one float stored as 4 bytes, the float only needs x.xxx digits (from 0.005 to 1.000) how could I store using less space if possible? Also, it's 10 bytes of info but since it's an array it takes up 38 bytes, is there a more efficient way to serialize and store it?

Comment: What language are you using? Assuming C-like, use a `short int` and divide by 1000 when you display. You'll also avoid floating-point rounding issues by doing this.

Comment: This question is not at all clear. What is six bytes, the information in one element in the array? What does it mean to be a “byte array” of “info”? If the “info” is not a structure of six bytes, what is six bytes? Commonly, a `float` is four bytes. So is that four of the six bytes? What does “it’s 10 bytes of info” mean; we were just told the “info” is “6 individual bytes.” What does “since it’s an array it takes up 38 bytes” mean? There is no rule that an array has to take up 38 bytes, so why does being an array cause it to take up 38 bytes?

Comment: If the values are from .005 to 1.000, are they all (near) multiples of .005? In that case, there are only 200 possible values, so you only need eight bits to represent them. To encode, multiply by 200 and round to the nearest integer to allow for floating-point issues. To decode, divide by 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

struct ShortFloat { short beforeFloatingPoint : 4, afterFloatingPoint : 10 }; - 2^4 > 10, 2^10 > 1000, you can use 2 bytes to store such "short" float numbers and for arithmetics you can override operations, that's if you're using C++.